# RDP session locked out

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

After setting up an automated deployment env, we somehow locked up the RDP account. I get the following message:

> As a security precaution, the user account has been locked because
>   there were too many login attempts or password change attempts. Wait a
>   while before trying again

How much is "a while"? Specifically, where is this limit set up, and what are the default values?

Comment: [Account lockout duration security policy setting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/account-lockout-duration).